# How to access Variable document ID in nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am writing  into firebase  according to this code

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user){
      Firestore.instance
          .collection('cards')
            .document(user.email)
          .collection('tokens').add({
      'tokenid': token.tokenId,
      'Email': user.email,
      }).then((val){
      });
      print("saveedd");
    });
```

I need to access that `user.email` document Id in `nodejs` for each user separately. As each user have different email address or `user.uid.`
I am writing a Cloud Function how to access document Id generated by me in Firestore which is unique for each user.  I put ??? into the Cloud Function code snippet below where I need to access that document Id.

```
exports.StripeSource =functions.firestore.document('cards/{???}/tokens/{tokenid}').onCreate(async (tokenSnap,context) => {

console.log('this is log');

  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question you should do as follows:

```
exports.StripeSource = functions.firestore.document('cards/{cardId}/tokens/{tokenid}').onCreate(async (tokenSnap,context) => {

     //.....
     const cardId = context.params.cardId;
     //.....

})
```

The [`context`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext) parameter provides information about the function's execution. `context` contains, among others, the [`params`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext.html#params) field, which is "an object containing the values of the wildcards in the path parameter representing the Firestore document to listen to for events". More details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters) in the doc.

Comment: thanks sir I got my answer you are awesome. stay blessed